# If Equal to Value in Other Range, Then Highlight Value in Range

Tags: excel, lookup, highlight, conditional-formatting, excel-match

I have two columns of data - a reference column `All Names` and another list `Performer` of names that meet a certain criterion (the criterion is not relevant here).

`All Names` contains 2,029 names, `Performer` contains ~120 names.  They are not matched up (i.e. `Bill Smith` does not sit beside `Bill Smith`, but rather beside `Jessica Hart`).

What I want to do is to check each name in `Performer` against the list `All Names` and, if it exists within `All Names`, I then want to **highlight the value in `All Names`** so that I can easily identify it.

For example, if `Bill Smith` (which resides in `Performers`) also exists within `All Names`, then I want to highlight the value `Bill Smith` in `All Names` for easy visual reference.

**Here is an example of how my data appears:**

```
ALL NAMES         |PERFORMER
------------------|--------------
Bill Smith        |       
Jane Smith        |       
Vikram Gujeravi   |Enoch Thistle
Sebastian Davies  |Nicole Dunning
Enoch Thistle     |
Nicole Dunning    |Bill Smith
```

This should result in the names of Enoch, Nicole and Bill being highlighted in the `All Names` column.

**Example:**

```
IF `Performers`("BILL SMITH") exists within `All Names`
THEN highlight `All Names`("BILL SMITH") yellow
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You are surely aware that you need basically a nested loop: in the outer loop you go through all cell of the Performers, take the value and check in the inner loop all values of "All Names" whether it matches - it's all!

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this and have done similar things; I have successfully located the values within the range using various functions, such as `VLOOKUP`, `MATCH`, and other similar functions, but I cannot get it to highlight the value within `All Names`.  I have tried using a formula in Conditional Formatting whereby if any value in `All Names` matches any value in `Performers` then it is to be highlighted yellow, but this doesn't function correctly and highlights the incorrect cells.  It's the part where it highlights the value in `All Names` yellow that is problematic.

Comment: Let us look into your source code, dude!

Comment: Believe me, if I could I would!  It is highly confidential data, so I cannot even provide a glimpse of it I'm afraid.  However, I have just added in some dummy data which is a very basic version of how my data appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a conditional formatting on the first column:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$17,1,FALSE)>0,1,0)
```

A2 is the location of the first "all names" and B2:B17 is the range of "performer"

Answer (score 2):

Select ColumnA and use:

```
=MATCH(A1,B:B,0)>1
```

thus:

[image: SO23907648 example]

for a slightly simpler formula. The main difference with accepted A probably being that since such formatting is *Conditional* - IF is not normally necessary..

Comment: Indeed - a simpler solution!